# MySQL change column name on EMPTY table, takes very long

Tags: mysql, performance

Running a local Mysql instance. In my DB, I misspelled a column name (stret to street). So I wrote a query:

```
alter table address change Stret Street VARCHAR(20);
```

This table has just been created and contains zero records. I know there are various threads asking why it take so long but all of their tables has 100,000+ rows. I have nothing! Why did this query take 1 hour 13 min 15.76 sec?

I know I could have dropped and recreated the table, I am just curious as to why this "simple" change could take so long?

Edit: Found out the reason. I was debugging a program that uses this db and stopped in the middle (without terminating the program) to change the column name. Once I stopped tomcat everything is instant again. So presumably the table was locked so the query was held up. I am using InnoDB. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What's the DBEngine your using? InnoDB, MyIsam...? Also, how big is the whole database?

Comment: Anything in the server logs?  What version of MySQL?  What O/S and filesystem?

Comment: Maybe the table was locked? Can you reproduce it and look at it closer?

Comment: I must have locked my DB like 5 times while using Sqlalchemy in iPython terminal. Then go to correct a table attribute, and it hangs....duh....locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you do this you might want to `TRUNCATE TABLE address` (very fast but will reset your `AUTO_INCREMENT` column counters) or `OPTIMIZE TABLE address` (a bit slower, but doesn't alter data) in order to flush out any left-over data that is deleted but not vacuumed from the database.

An alternative is to `CREATE TABLE _address LIKE address`, run the alteration to the clone, then switch `_address` for `address` using `RENAME TABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the **[docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)**

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original
>   table. MySQL waits for other operations that are modifying the table,
>   then proceeds. It incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes
>   the original table, and renames the new one.

If you are using InnoDB, it does the above **even for** single column renames, while with `MyISAM`, it does not create a copy and modifies table's `frm` file.
That would explain the time taken probably, for a large table, due to memory constraints.

You could try obtaining a **[query execution-plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)**.